# Previous vs Previously

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

Looking for correct usage here:

...show previous visited locations

...show previously visited locations

previous is an adjective, previously is an adverb

but is visited the verb being described?

or is it locations which is a noun?

Comment: It's because *previous* is an adjective that I would use " … show **previous locations** visited." The use of *previous visited locations* seems ungrammatical to me. Off the top of my head, I'm unaware of acceptable adjective+verb+noun phrases, but I could just not be thinking of an example currently. However, note that " … show **previously** visited locations" is also fine, because, in this use, *previously* is an adverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously

"visited" should be treated as an adjective.